# Upgrading Hibernate 3.1 to 3.6 for a performande boost

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Currently running a live e-commerce site that uses Hibernate 3.1 and JBoss Treecache in front of a MySQL 5.0 database. Database is medium-sized (1.5-Gb) with the lion's share of the data among three or four tables.

If I upgrade the e-commerce site to use Hibernate 3.6 solely for performance reasons, am I going to see any difference? Will I have better luck focusing on upgrading JBoss Treecache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having performance issues, you would probably get more of a performance boost from:

1. Optimizing your table structures or indexes.  Stuff in the db itself.
2. Optimizing your queries.  When using hibernate, if performance is crucial, you are going to need to use hql to construct optimal sql.  Also to just pull out the data you need.
3. Invest in 2nd level caching.

You need to do the diligence and figure out where you are slow.  Is it one or two particular queries?  Is it transmitting data from server to client? What?

I doubt you will see any significant performance increase from just upgrading hibernate versions.

Comment: Hibernate and the underlying db work well, my issues are around the handling of the sets POJOs after the querying is done. Working from bottom-to-top, I will look at post-Hibernate solutions next. Thanks!